# Run multiple functions at once node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a script with the goal to start multiple server instances at the same time. Is this possible in node js? Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');

startServer("apache", 1, "88.***.***.**");
startServer("apache", 2, "5.9.***.**");
startServer("apache", 3, "5.9.***.**");
startServer("apache", 4, "5.9.**.**");
startServer("apache", 5, "5.9.*.**");

function startServer(software, instance, ip){

  var web = require("./server/" + software + ".js");

  var webserver = new web(express, "Random server", instance, ip, 10, 0, 1);
  webserver.install();

}
```

Thanks for your help :)

//Edit

the .install() function is running a shell script that needs minutes to finish.

Comment: Define "at the same time". If `webserver.install()` is async, the instances would start "almost" at the same time (a few ms between each).

Comment: Use pm2 in cluster mode